# How to check if two instances of my class are equal?

Tags: c++

I have made a class, in which the user have to enter his address. My question is how to implement a member function that determines whether the the data members of an instance of my Address class are equal to another instance?

Comment: Seems you're just learning OOP.  You should have a copy constructor, a destructor and overload the = operator for completeness of your class.  Also, instead of having a print() member function, you could overload the << operator then just std::cout << address << std::endl; to output the address.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to know if two addresses are equal. For this you can implement the equal to operator (`==`), where you can check if `addressA == addressB` by checking if all the address fields are equal. For example:

```
    bool operator==(const Address& rhs)
    {
        return (this->country == rhs.country) && (this->city== rhs.city) && 
               (this->street_name == rhs.street_name) && (this->street_number == rhs.street_number) &&
               (this->zip_code == rhs.zip_code) && 
               (this->GPS_coordinates_latitude = rhs.GPS_coordinates_latitude) &&
               (this->GPS_coordinates_longitude == rhs.GPS_coordinates_longitude);
    }
```

Comment: You should add 'const' to rhs.